# Invalid Pointer Passed By Address-of(&) Operator

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Alright, so I'm practicing with C++ classes and pointers. When suddenly...
If I try to get the address of my object passed in the parameters, it gives me an invalid address.

What is going on here?

P.S You can ignore the if statement, it shouldn't be relevant to this particular problem.
[Picture of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4IQ3.png)
.

```
int ChainLinkz::chainCount = 0;

ChainLinkz::ChainLinkz(int i) {
    data = i;
    chainID = chainCount++;
    fLink = this;
    addr = this;
    nLink = 0;
    printf("Created Link with Value: %i  Addr: %x.\n", data, this);
}

ChainLinkz *ChainLinkz::next() {
    if (nLink)
        return nLink;
    else
        return 0;
}

ChainLinkz *ChainLinkz::last() {
    ChainLinkz * lastLink = fLink;
    while (lastLink->next()) {
        lastLink = lastLink->next();
    }
    return lastLink;
}

ChainLinkz ChainLinkz::addLink(ChainLinkz link) {
    if (link.nLink) {
        if (&link == link.fLink) { // Replace fLink with new address in all instances of previous chain | Fix the old chain
            ChainLinkz *t_link = link.nLink;
            while (t_link->next()) {
                t_link = t_link->next();
                t_link->fLink = link.nLink;
            }
        } else { // Replace nLink for previous link | Fix the old chain
            ChainLinkz *t_link = link.fLink;
            while (t_link != &link)
                t_link = t_link->next();
            t_link->nLink = link.next();
        }
    }
    last()->nLink = link.addr;
    printf("\n&link: %x   |    Real Addr: %x \n\n", (ChainLinkz*)&link, link.addr);
    link.nLink = 0; //Update values to new chain
    link.fLink = fLink;

    return link;
}

ChainLinkz ChainLinkz::addLink(ChainLinkz *link) {
    printf("Overloader: %x.\n", link);
    return addLink(*link);
}

ChainLinkz ChainLinkz::operator>>(ChainLinkz link) {
    return addLink(link);
}
ChainLinkz ChainLinkz::operator>>(ChainLinkz *link) {
    printf("Overloader: %x.\n", link);
    return addLink(*link);
}
```

Comment: Please put the code in your question!

Comment: `"%p"` should be used to `printf` a pointer, not `"%x"`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But the value given by & is still incorrect. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Results using %p yield https://i.gyazo.com/52c9bf3f4ca8f29d805fe7863a5fc830.png

Comment: In what way is the pointer invalid? It should point to the parammeter on the stack. That is a temporary, so in the end, your list will only contain rubbish.

Comment: Look at the picture I linked. The address returned by & is different than the address the object was actually created on.

***EDIT***
I think I understand what you mean, I'll post back on results..

Comment: Problem solved by calling via a reference instead of passing the object itself. https://i.gyazo.com/8859fad82fbbc98cf0bcee87e45b7310.png

Comment: `&link == link.fLink` will always be false, because `link` was passed by value

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by using references instead of passing the object itself.

```
ChainLinkz ChainLinkz::addLink(ChainLinkz &link) {
    printf("Overloaded New: %p\n", &link);
    return addLink(&link);
}

ChainLinkz ChainLinkz::addLink(ChainLinkz *link) {
    if (link->nLink) {
        if (link == link->fLink) { // Replace fLink with new address in all instances of previous chain | Fix the old chain
            ChainLinkz *t_link = link->nLink;
            while (t_link->next()) {
                t_link = t_link->next();
                t_link->fLink = link->nLink;
            }
        }
        else { // Replace nLink for previous link | Fix the old chain
            ChainLinkz *t_link = link->fLink;
            while (t_link != link)
                t_link = t_link->next();
            t_link->nLink = link->next();
        }
    }
    last()->nLink = link;
    link->nLink = 0; //Update values to new chain
    link->fLink = fLink;
    return *link;
}

ChainLinkz ChainLinkz::operator>>(ChainLinkz &link) {
    return addLink(&link);
}
ChainLinkz ChainLinkz::operator>>(ChainLinkz *link) {
    printf("Overloaded: %p.\n", link);
    return addLink(link);
}
```